# Checking if condition with javascript variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a string array like this

```
function checkAlreadyShortlisted()
{
    var shortListed = new Array();                    
    shortListed = '["Mr. Andrew Severinsen", "Mr. Tom Herron", "Ms. Samantha Smithson-Biggs", "Mr. Efrem Bonfiglioli", "Mr. Giles Forster"]';
    var candidateName = '';

    $('.searchResultCandidateDiv').each(function(i, obj) {
                    
        candidateName = $(this).find('.viewResumeAnchor').text();  // Get the text from the particular div
        console.log(candidateName);

        if(candidateName == shortListed[4])   // Copied the value from Set
            {
            console.log('Got from Set');
        }              
        else if(shortListed[4] == "Mr. Giles Forster") // Copied the value from anchor
        {
            console.log('Got from Anchron text');
        }
    });
}
```

In the div looped I have to check if the name in the shortlisted array is present or not.

These are values I copied from browser console log

> Mr. Efrem Bonfiglioli
>
> Mr. Giles Forster

Checking condition with above text is working fine, but if I try to check the values with array string it is not working properly. But text are similar any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Variable `shortListed` not holding array values, but strings. Remove quote `'` around it :

```
shortListed = ["Mr. Andrew Severinsen", "Mr. Tom Herron", "Ms. Samantha Smithson-Biggs", "Mr. Efrem Bonfiglioli", "Mr. Giles Forster"];
```

Then you're able to accessing it by `shortListed[0], shortListed[1], shortListed[n],..`

More easy way to check array values contains something, i would like to use [`$.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) built in function in jQuery.
As this function will return `-1` if value did't not existed, otherwise will returned index if found that. See example below how to use that :

```
if ( $.inArray('Mr. Tom Herron',shortListed) !== -1 ) {    
  alert('Found it');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/kf8n784d/)